# Code Duplication: Should I use a separate method or Builder Pattern?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I have the following 2 methods (some codes omitted for brevity) in my Java (Spring) app and I want to reduce duplicated blocks in these methods. At this point, after making some research, some people suggesting Builder Pattern, some of them another similar one Template Method. I also think that, I could simply create 2 separate methods and move each repeated code blocks to these methods.

However, I have no experience about this issue and I would like to ask you first to follow the most proper ways. So, how should I reduce the code duplication in the following 2 methods? I also think to use inheritance, but I am really confused with finding a proper way.

**Not:** I omitted my code and use a simple code for brevity:

```
@Override
public MultipartFile exportAaaaa() throws IOException {

    // repeated code block I
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = workbook.createSheet(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE));
    rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);    
    //

    // private block to this method
    final Page<Aaaaa> page = aaaaaService.findAll());

    // ...

    // repeated code block II
    outputFile = File.createTempFile(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE), EXTENSION);
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggingUtils.error("Writing is failed ", e);
    }
    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE).concat(EXTENSION);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
    //
}
```

```
@Override
public MultipartFile exportBbbbb() throws IOException {

    // repeated code block I
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = workbook.createSheet(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE));
    rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);    
    //

    // private block to this method
    final Page<Bbbbb> page = bbbbbService.findBy Uuid(uuid));

    // ...

    // repeated code block II
    outputFile = File.createTempFile(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE), EXTENSION);
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggingUtils.error("Writing is failed ", e);
    }
    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE).concat(EXTENSION);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
    //
}
```

Comment: I suggest posting your actual, working code for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I see here, that the duplicated code is a logging(or console printing).
But it is not clear in this example what are **aService** and **bService** do? May be they have a different logics inside? As I see they return the different result.
But if **A.class** and **B.class** are the implementation of one interface, and **aService** and **bService** are also implementations of one interface. It could be the one method. Maybe)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. Sorry, it is misunderstood and for this reason I posted full code. Could you pls have a look at and update your answer?

Comment: Chico? Any reply pls?

Answer (score 0):

If `aaaaaService` and `bbbbbService` share a common interface, for example

```
interface PageService<T> {
    Page<T> findAll();
}
```

then we can use a single method with type arguments.

```
private <T> MultipartFile export(Service<T> service) throws IOException {
    // repeated code block I
    final Page<T> page = service.findAll());
    // repeated code block II
}
```

We can either declare this method as `public` or keep the previous methods as cover methods, which depends on whether you want clients to handle/access the underlying service and on whether you may change the interface or superclass indicated by `@Override`.

```
public MultipartFile exportAaaaa() throws IOException {
    // assuming that 'aaaaaService' is a class member
    return export(aaaaaService);
}
```

---

If there is no common interface, I'd simply extract the common code blocks to separate methods.

```
private MultipartFile exportAaaaa() throws IOException {
    prepareWorkbook(/* parameters */);
    final Page<T> page = aaaaaService.findAll());
    constructOutput(/* parameters */);
}

private /* return type */ prepareWorkbook(/* parameters */) {
    // repeated code block I
}

private /* return type */ constructOutput(/* parameters */) {
    // repeated code block II
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable explanations. But the main point that I focused on is the repeated code parts rather than service. So, ignore service (assume that they completely make unrelated things) and update your answer by suggesting a proper way. Should I extract the 2 repeated parts to 2 separate methods and call them in these `exportAaaaa` and `exportBbbbb` methods?

Comment: @Jonathan I addressed both alternatives in my answer. If there is a common interface, you can make use of it. If you, however, don't want to rely on the service fulfilling a specific contract, you may choose the second approach I highlighted - which is to extract the two duplicated parts into dedicated methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the duplication in your code can be extracted pretty easily into separate methods:

```
private void doCodeBlockI() {
    // repeated code block I
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = workbook.createSheet(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE));
    rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);    
}    

private MultipartFile doCodeBlockII() {
    // repeated code block II
    outputFile = File.createTempFile(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE), 
    EXTENSION);
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggingUtils.error("Writing is failed ", e);
    }
    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE).concat(EXTENSION);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
}    

@Override
public MultipartFile exportAaaaa() throws IOException {
    doCodeBlockI();

    // private block to this method
    final Page<Aaaaa> page = aaaaaService.findAll();

    // ...

    return doCodeBlockII();
}

@Override
public MultipartFile exportBbbbb() throws IOException {
    doCodeBlockI();

    // private block to this method
    final Page<Bbbbb> page = bbbbbService.findByUuid(uuid);

    // ...

    return doCodeBlockII();
}
```

Another way of achieving this goal would be to use an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Exporter {

    public MultipartFile export() throws IOException {

        // repeated code block I
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE));
        rowCount = new AtomicInteger(0);    
        //

        // private block will be called inside the abstract method
        doPrivateBlock();
    
        // repeated code block II
        outputFile = File.createTempFile(TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE), EXTENSION);
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LoggingUtils.error("Writing is failed ", e);
        }
        final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

        final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(TITLE).concat(EXTENSION);
        return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
        //
    }

    protected abstract void doPrivateBlock();
}
```

Then extend it twice, implementing the `doPrivateBlock()` method:

```
public class AaaaaExporter extends Exporter {

    AaaaaService aaaaaService; // need to instantiate this

    public AaaaaExporter() {}

    @Override
    private void doPrivateBlock() {
        // private block to this method
        final Page<Aaaaa> page = aaaaaService.findAll());

        // ...
    }
}

public class BbbbbExporter extends Exporter {

    BbbbbService bbbbbService; // need to instantiate this

    public BbbbbExporter() {}

    @Override
    private void doPrivateBlock() {
        // private block to this method
            final Page<Bbbbb> page = bbbbbService.findByUuid(uuid));

        // ...
    }
}
```

I've ignored the shared fields that are being used in your code (e.g. `workbook`), you will need to either add them as arguments to the export(...) method or add them as fields to the `Exporter` class and instantiate them along with your class, it will depend on their scope which is not well-defined in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be a proper and simplest solution. On the other hand, what about if other classes have also these `doCodeBlockI` and `doCodeBlockII`? In this case, how should I move these methods (`doCodeBlockI` and `doCodeBlockII`) and use them in this method and from other export classes? Should I make them (`doCodeBlockI` and `doCodeBlockII`) static method and call from this class? Or is there any need to use inheritance?

Comment: It really depends on your specific needs, but yes, a helper class might do the trick (you can also pass services as required as parameters, and these services can have different behaviors according to context (e.g. `Printer` vs `CloudPrinter` vs `DummyPrinter` all implementing the `IPrinter`'s `print()` method).

Comment: This is the point that makes me confused as I have not enough experience. So, could you please add these 2 approach to you answer as Update? I would be really grateful and learn so much from such kind of examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reply please?